# get textinput value inside MDApp

Tags: class, kivy, screen, self, textinput

Good afternoon, I have a great difficulty, which seems easy to solve.
The question is as follows:
I have my **TextInput** created this way, in my :

```
KV = """
WindowManager:
    ScreenLogin:
    ScreenPaginaInicial:
    PaginaEntradas:
        id: data_scr
    ScreenInicioProducao:  
    PaginaMovInterna:     
    PaginaMovExterna:      
    PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalInterna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalExterna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Externa:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Externa:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Externa:

<ScreenLogin>:
    name: "ScreenLogin"
    FloatLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Image:
                size_hint: .3, .3
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .75}
                source: 'G:\O meu disco\Gestao_Stocks\logo.png'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                spacing: 5
                size_hint: .7, .37
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
                Label:
                    text: "Utilizador"
                    size_hint_x: .3
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                    allow_copy: True
                TextInput:
                    id: utilizador
                    multiline: False
                    halign: 'center'
                    focus: True
                    size_hint_x: 5

"""


class PLASbritos(MDApp):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_tables = None
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def login(self):
        utilizador = self.root.ids.utilizador.text
        print(utilizador)
        password = '1'
        #Implemesta regras para acesso. Exemplo:
        if utilizador == '1' and password == '1':
        .........................................
        .........................................
        ........................................
    else:
        ........................................
```

I would like to access the **utilizador** through the **textinput(id: utilizador)**

```
error:
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I've already looked for all the information on google, I've seen videos on youtube, and I can't find anything. What seemed to be the easiest, is extremely difficult, if someone can help me, I am extremely grateful.

I thank you in advance for any attention you can give me.

I've already looked for all the information on google, inclusive in stackoverflow similiar problems, I've seen videos on youtube, and I can't find anything. What seemed to be the easiest, is extremely difficult, if someone can help me, I am extremely grateful.

Comment: Are you trying to put a `TextInput` inside a `Label`? I don't think that will work.

Comment: Good morning .... I have already made the necessary changes. Thank you very much for the time you took to help me. I hope my changes are enough.

Comment: In your `KV`, the contents of the `FloatLayout` are indented too much.

Comment: Sorted out
https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/hztzyw/attributeerror_super_object_has_no_attribute/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
.kv